# Context API return undefined is not an object when in use with React-Native and React navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

Okay so I've been having this problem for two days and can't seem to figure out where or what exactly is my problem. I'm using `react-navigation` documentation along with their authentication flow in the hopes of building a login/register/home screens. The problem I'm facing is that even though I've tested my API endpoints and get valid json data I'm unable to display it and get the `undefined is not an object` error.

**The AuthState.js**

```
  import React,{useReducer} from 'react'
  import AuthContext from './authContext'
  import AuthReducer from './AuthReducer'
  import axios from 'axios';
  import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
  import {LOGIN_SUCCESS, REGISTER_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILURE, REGISTER_FAILURE, LOGOUT, GET_USER} from 
 '../../types'

 const AuthState = props => {

const initialState = {
    authUser:null,
    loading:true,
    error:null,
    isAuthenticated:false
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, initialState);


const register = async(email, password, fname, lname) =>{

  const obj = {
      username:email,
      password:password,
      firstName:fname,
      lastName:lname
  }

  const config = {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
  }

  try {

  const userToken = await axios.post('http://192.168.0.14:5000/api/auth/signup', obj, config);

  dispatch({type:REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload:userToken.data});

  } catch (error) {

  }

}

const login = async(email, password) =>{

  const obj = {
      username:email,
      password:password,
  }

  const config = {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
  }

  try {

  const userToken = await axios.post('http://192.168.0.14:5000/api/auth/login', obj, config);

  dispatch({type:LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload:userToken.data});

  } catch (error) {

  }

}

const getUser = async() =>{

  let token = await setAuthorizatinToken();

   try {
    const res = await axios.get('http://192.168.0.14:5000/api/auth/', {
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'x-auth':token
        }
    });

    let obj = res.data;
    console.log(obj);
   dispatch({type:GET_USER, payload:obj});

   } catch (error) {

   }
}

const setAuthorizatinToken = async() =>{

    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
   if(token){
       return token;
   } else {
      return 401;
   }
}

return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{
        authUser:state.authUser,
        loading:state.loading,
        error:state.error,
        register,
        login,
        getUser,
        isAuthenticated:state.isAuthenticated,
        setAuthorizatinToken
    }}>
        {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
)
}

 export default AuthState
```

**The AuthReducer.js**

```
 import {LOGIN_SUCCESS, REGISTER_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILRURE,
 REGISTER_FAILURE, LOGOUT, GET_USER} from '../../types'
 import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';


export default async(state,action) =>{
     switch(action.type) {
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
    case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', action.payload);
        return {
            ...state,
            loading:false,
            isAuthenticated:true
        }
        break;
    } catch (error) {

    }
    break;
    case GET_USER:
    return{
        ...state,
        loading:false,
        isAuthenticated:true,
        authUser:action.payload
    }

    default:
        break;
   }
}
```

App.js

```
return (   
  <NavigationContainer>
   <AuthState>
      <Stack.Navigator>
         <Stack.Screen name="NoToken" component={NoneStack} options={{headerShown:false}}/>            
      </Stack.Navigator>
   </AuthState>
  </NavigationContainer>
 );
```

And finally the stack screen

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from 'react'
import AuthContext from '../context/AuthContext/authContext';
import AuthState from '../context/AuthContext/AuthState';
import Register from '../components/Register/Register';
import Loading from '../components/Loading/Loading';
import Login from '../components/Login/Login'
import Home from '../components/Home/Home';
const None = createStackNavigator();
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

//stack navigator for tackling user authentication
const none = () => {

const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

//check if the user has been loaded from asyncstorage
const {user, loading, getUser, isAuthenticated} = authContext;

useEffect(() => {
  //get the token if there is any and check it
  //if it's authorized, switch to home screen,
  //else, switch to login screen again
  getUser();
}, [])

 return (

     <None.Navigator>
     {/* if not, return a screen which prompts him to input his credentials */}
     {isAuthenticated == false ? (
       <>
       <None.Screen name="Register" component={Register} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
       <None.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
       </>
     ) : (
     // if yes, return the home screen component
       <None.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
     )}
     </None.Navigator>
 )
}

export default none
```

The strange thing is that after I either login or create an account, I get switched to the Home screen, signifying that the state has been updated, but when it comes to actually use the data in the Home component, the above error is mentioned. Any help would be appreciated!